# Find the most common colour in an image

Tags: php, colors, gd

How can I use PHP to find the most common colour in an image?

Comment: I would -1 for calling me a fool, but I decide I don't want a rep of 787.

Comment: +1 for calling americans fools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry...

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3370.html